# Type hinting for scipy sparse matrices

Tags: python, scipy

How do you type hint scipy sparse matrices, such as `CSR, CSC, LIL` etc.? Below is what I have been doing, but it doesn't feel right:

```py
def foo(mat: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix):
    # Do whatever
```

What do we do if our function can accept multiple types of scipy sparse matrices (i.e any of them)?

Comment: Type hinting in `numpy` is a relatively new feature, and probably hasn't been extended to `scipy`.  Technically each sparse matrix is an instance of a `sparse` class.  There is a `csr_matrix` class, a `lil_matrix` class, etc.  Who/what is supposed to pay attention to this hint?  Programmers, or some coding tool like `mypy`?

Comment: Many of the `sparse` functions accept any of the formats, converting the input to some a preferred format for processing.  For example most calculations are done with `csr`.  None of the `sparse` code uses type hinting (that I've seen).

Comment: @hpaulj it's mainly for me/programmers, so it's not the end of the world if it there is no type hinting. I was also planning to have my sparse function accept any format, which is what I was alluding to in my second question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of `csr, csc, lil` are types of `scipy.sparse.base.spmatrix`:

```py
from scipy import sparse
c1 = sparse.lil.lil_matrix
c2 = sparse.csr.csr_matrix
c3 = sparse.csc.csc_matrix

print(c1.__bases__[0])
print(c2.__base__.__base__.__base__)
print(c3.__base__.__base__.__base__)
```

Output:

```
<class 'scipy.sparse.base.spmatrix'>
<class 'scipy.sparse.base.spmatrix'>
<class 'scipy.sparse.base.spmatrix'>
```

So you have an option to:

```py
def foo(mat: scipy.sparse.base.spmatrix):
    # Do whatever
```

Answer (score 6):

`scipy.sparse.base` is now deprecated. You should use `scipy.sparse.spmatrix` instead, which provides a base class for all sparse matrices.

```
def foo(mat: scipy.sparse.spmatrix):
    # Whatever you want
    pass
```

Comment: Link to the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.spmatrix.html